# How to instal phpab using cmd line on Linux?

Tags: php, linux

I am trying to run a build.xml file with ant but I get the following errors :

```
build.xml:44: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "phpab": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:475)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:610)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute$Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Execute.java:862)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:481)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:495)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:631)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:672)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:498)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:811)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:164)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:81)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:468)
        ... 24 more

Total time: 0 seconds
```

How can I install phpab on linux?

Comment: Did `apt-get install phpab` or its equivalent not work?

Comment: -bash: apt-get: command not found . I am fairly new to linux and I am used to yum . which package do I need to install to get apt-get working? thanks

Comment: Your package manager generally depends on your distro of Linux, which you have not specified. But running `yum install phpab` should do something.

Comment: I am using fedora 13 . $yum install phpab
Loaded plugins: presto
Setting up Install Process
No package phpab available.
Nothing to do

Comment: doing an update to yum to see if it sorts the problem

Comment: no luck. still does not work .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download it to a bin dir:

```
sudo wget -N --no-check-certificate -O /bin/phpab http://phpab.net/phpab-1.10.3.phar
```

chmod it to be an executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /bin/phpab
```

and then test it:

```
phpab -v
```

should give you

```
phpab 1.10.3 - Copyright (C) 2009 - 2013 by Arne Blankerts
```

File source: https://github.com/theseer/Autoload

Answer (score 0):

for fedora this should work:

```
# yum install /usr/bin/phpab
```

or install with direct package name:

```
# yum install php-theseer-autoload
```

in case if interested, the fedora package git repo is here: http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/cgit/php-theseer-autoload.git/